# Nesting If and Or statements

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to nest several columns into an If statement that utilizes both And and Or functions. I'm so far unable to come up with a function that works.

Rules:

- If Act Conf Years OR Act Conf Months > 0 then output "Confinement"
- If Act Prob years OR Act Prob Months > 0 then output "Probation"
- If (Act Conf Years OR Act Conf Months > 0 ) AND (Act Prob years OR Act Prob Months >0) then output "Both"

The formula I came up with was:

```
IF(OR(D3>0,E3>0),"Confinement",IF(OR(G3>0,H3>0),"Probation",IF(OR(D3>0,E3>0,AND(G3>0,H3>0),"Both"))
```

However, that doesn't work. I know the issue is somewhere in the part after "Probation". But am not sure how to appropriately stack the OR and AND functions.

Alternatively, can this somehow be done with Power Query, Power Pivot, or some other add on?

Comment: `IF(OR(D3>0,E3>0),"Confinement",IF(OR(G3>0,H3>0),"Probation",IF(And(OR(D3>0,E3>0),OR(G3>0,H3>0)),"Both"))`?  I think the issue is your final statement - you do `Or(And)` and it should be `And(or(),or())` I think.

Comment: Is it possible for the record to show no confinement and no probation? If not, you can simplify this to two IFs.

Comment: I tried using And with nested Or's within and Excel still wouldn't process it. Simplifying the formula as @Excellll indicated worked perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "Neither Confinement nor Probation" is impossible in your data, you can use a simpler formula.

```
=IF(D3+E3>0,IF(G3+H3>0,"Both","Confinement"),"Probation")
```

If it is possible that the record shows neither confinement nor probation, you can use this formula:

```
=IF(D3+E3>0,IF(G3+H3>0,"Both","Confinement"),IF(G3+H3>0,"Probation","Neither"))
```

Comment: For whatever reason, neither of the other two answers stacking AND and OR functions work. I don't know if its my excel or something else.

However, your second option works perfectly. Neither is definitely a result (as some of the rows aren't convicted so they aren't sentenced to anything or are sent to a diversion program or something else..mostly don't care, just need Confined, Probation, or both!). 

So thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your third ("Both") condition contains two OR statements (and an AND).  Your formula did not include the second OR.

You want `AND( OR (), OR() )`

Before:

```
IF(OR(D3>0,E3>0),"Confinement",
IF(OR(G3>0,H3>0),"Probation",
IF(OR(D3>0,E3>0,AND(G3>0,H3>0),"Both"))
```

After:

```
IF(OR(D3>0,E3>0),"Confinement",
IF(OR(G3>0,H3>0),"Probation",
IF(AND(OR(D3>0,E3>0),OR(G3>0,H3>0)),"Both")))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative version, without AND

```
IF(OR(D3>0, E3>0), IF(OR(G3>0, H3>0), "Both", "Confinement"),
   IF(OR(G3>0, H3>0), "Probation", ))
```

The logic is:

- If Conf, (If Prob (too), then "Both", else it's just "Confinement"),
- If Prob, then "Probation", (*optional*: else "None")

Where Conf is (Act Conf Years > 0 OR Act Conf Months > 0)
Prob is (Act Prob Years > 0 OR Act Prob Months > 0)

You can make it simpler by substituting the `OR` part with temporary variable Conf and Prob (yes, algebra works in logic too)